# How do I reset MS Word toolbar button state on new document

Tags: templates, vba, ms-word

I have a request from a User Group to implement the following:

1. Introduce a set of templates that
   have some Hidden Text on the page as
   instructions
2. Display the Hidden
   Text the first time a document is
   created using the templates
3. Introduce a custom button to toggle
   the Hidden Text display

1) The templates are now created.  Manual toggle of Hidden Text works.
2) should be dealt with using Auto_New to set the state of Hidden Text

3) is causing me grief.  I have the code that toggles the Hidden Text and the State of the custom button when I am in the templates and the Auto New code is fine when I am in the templates covered in 1), however the state of the button also needs to be reset when I am in *other* templates.

What I need is something to set the status of the button depending on the Hidden Text setting whenever any document is created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a macro under Normal that sets the button according to the status of HiddenText.

Not exactly what I want, in that the button may be in the wrong position when changing window views, but it's good enough...